# How to get mouse coordinates from a shape inside canvas and change 0,0 point

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

is there anyway to get the mouse coordinates inside an certain shape? Also, is there any chance to change the 0,0 (X,Y) point to the lower left corner of this certain shape?

I've not found anything to help me figure out these doubts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a 2 step process to get the mouse coordinates inside a shape.

First, use `stage.getMousePosition` to get the mouse position on the stage.

Second, subtract the object's `getX()` and `getY()` to determine the position of the mouse inside the object.

```
  kineticObject.on('mousemove', function() {
    var mousePos = stage.getMousePosition();
    var x = mousePos.x - this.getX();
    var y = mousePos.y - this.getY();
  });
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "change the 0,0 point" but you can use `setOffsetY` to add an offset to any object.  So if I understand, this would do what you want:

```
  object.setOffsetY(object.getHeight());
```